# How do I disable runkit?

Tags: php, pecl, runkit

I want to temporarily disable runkit (or temporarily disable a PECL extension). Do somebody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment line

```
extension=runkit.so
```

in your php configuration file (php.ini).